# Is it possible to call specific functions before a Simulink simulation begins?

Tags: matlab, simulink

More specifically, I would like to automatically clear the workspace and all functions before a Simulink simulation starts. Is this possible? Are there hooks where I can define functions to be called before and, say, after each simulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [model callbacks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/ug/f4-122589.html).

You can set callbacks programmatically as described on the linked page, or just right-click on an empty spot in your model file, select *Model Properties*, then the *Callbacks* tab and enter the name of the function to be called after selecting the appropriate callback in the left pane.

In your case, the `StartFcn` callback seems appropriate.